# Drawing same number of each color from M white and N balls

Tags: probability, combinatorics

This one is from Gnedenko's Theory of Probability:

We have an urn containing $M$ white and $N$ black balls, where $M > N$. We are randomly drawing one ball at a time. What is the probability that at some point the number of black and white balls drawn will be the same?

My reasoning is as follows:

Consider a total of $M+N$ slots, which can be occupied by either a white or a black ball. In total there are $C_N^{M+N} == C_M^{M+N}$ arrangements. Since $N<M$, we are looking for arrangements where the first $2N$ slots are occupied by $N$ balls of each colour. Hence, there are $C_N^{2N}$ appropriate arrangements.

So, my answer is $C_N^{2N} / C_N^{M+N}$.

Any thoughts?

Comment: the number of choices are decreasing with time, aren't they?

Comment: or are the balls being replaced each time

Comment: Hint: rephrase the question in terms of lattice walks, and use the reflection principle.

Answer (score 0):

You are calculating the chance that you draw $N$ black and white balls out of the first $2N$ but have missed the additional chance that the first ball is black and the next $N$ are white among others.  The question asks for the probability that at some point you have drawn an equal number of balls, not only when you have drawn $2N$.  You need to sum the probabilities you have an equal number after $2,4,6,\ldots 2N$ draws , but avoid double counting when a particular draw has equal numbers more than once.

Comment: Ok, I see.
With the approach I presented, I was trying to find this probability as a relation of the number of beneficial permutations of all the balls to the total number of permutations.

Comment: I failed to see, that, for instance, **all** the permutation starting with $BW$ are valid

Comment: Yes, and those starting BBWW but you have to account for BWWB by counting it once, not twice.